# Databricks windows group by using sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm having trouble finding how to convert a pyspark window statement into the equivalent SQL format.

Example:

```
  eventsDF \
    .groupBy(
      "deviceId",
      window("eventTime", "10 minutes", "5 minutes")) \
    .count()
```

It should be something like:

```
   select window, deviceId, count(deviceId)
   from events
   group by window eventTime 10 minutes 5 minutes, deviceId
```

Comment: I'm not sure if SQL could handle the group by in the syntax you mentioned. What's your current situation? do you get any error or the result is different or ...?

Comment: It's all syntax errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix some syntax errors. The `window` should be wrapped in parentheses.

```
select
    window(eventTime, '10 minutes', '5 minutes'),
    deviceId,
    count(deviceId)
from events
group by
    window(eventTime, '10 minutes', '5 minutes'),
    deviceId
```

Comment: Thanks @mck, do you know if there is any documentation about the `window` syntax? Looks like the official doc is incomplete: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#window

Comment: @Emer see the pyspark docs: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.window

Answer (score 0):

I reckon the result of the following query is what you expected:

```
select deviceId, count(deviceId)
from events
group by `eventTime`, `10 minutes`,  `5 minutes`, `deviceId`
```

the `group by` will group the rows on all the windows you expect